# Detect mouse location after Silverlight window loaded

Tags: silverlight, mouse

I'm running a web page that has a SL 'box' in it.

I know how to use the MouseEnter and MouseLeave to detect if the mouse has entered the SL box or left it.

My question is how to detect if the mouse is inside or outside the SL box when it has just loaded.

Thanks.

Gilad.

Comment: Could you simply use the MouseMove event?

Comment: MouseMove event fires when the mouse actually moves over the SL box. but if the mouse is static the event does fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step post for building a Silverlight app that detects whether the mouse is over the Silverlight control when it is instantiated.

**Step 1**: Create a sample Silverlight application with Visual Studio (File / New Project / Silverlight Application)

**Step 2**: Edit the MainPage.xaml, and place the following code inside the UserControl's Grid:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock x:Name="x_Text" Text="Mouse Was Not Over" />
</Grid>
```

**Step 3**: Edit the MainPage.cs, and replace the MainPage class with the following code:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.MouseEnter += OnMouseEnter;
        base.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    void OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        x_Text.Text = "Mouse Was Over";
        base.MouseEnter -= OnMouseEnter;
    }

    void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(300 * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);
        timer.Tick += delegate(object senderTick, EventArgs eTick)
        {
            base.MouseEnter -= OnMouseEnter;
            timer.Stop();
        };
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

**Step 4**: Build and Run!  Try it with the mouse over the center of the Silverlight control and outside of the control to see the results!

Comment: Gilad, did this answer your question?  If so, could you mark it as answered?